# EVO 3d and drawText

Tags: android, 3d, stereo-3d

I'm creating a s3d app for the evo 3d and I have all the graphics setup and working perfectly in 3d. My question is, how do I use drawText and make it 3d? So far using drawText I can only get the text to show in the "left eye" view but in the "right eye" view nothing is displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the process of creating 3D apps on Android, but I'll assume you're producing a standard side-by-side picture. If this is true, you will have to call drawText twice with different coordinates - once for the left eye and once for the right eye.

The problem, however, with using drawText to show text over your scene is that it does not honour the eye displacement. It will show up exactly the same for both the eyes, which gives an impression of it being infinitely far away. This in turn messes up the impression of 3D of your entire scene, because you end up having something appearing infinitely far **covering** your objects, which then means it's still in front of them.

I suggest you find out whether the framework you're using for 3D graphics has a means to draw text in 3D space. In short, you would want a polygon onto which you will draw your text and position it in front of everything in your 3D scene. In other words, your text is no longer an overlay, but a part of the 3D scene.

As for the question of where to put this polygon so that it's always in front of everything else, I would suggest locking its position to the near clipping plane.

Hope this helps, hope I was clear enough :)